# Compare two arrays in powershell including order

Tags: arrays, powershell

I've quite simple situation where I've 2 arrays with 3 elements. The elements 99% will be the same but the order will be different. I need to know whether the order is correct/match or not. Below is simplified situation.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $aNICOrderOne = @("IBR","Service", "Admin")
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $aNICOrder = @("Service","IBR", "Admin")
$CompareNICOrderOne = Compare-Object $aNICOrder $aNICOrderOne -PassThru
if ("$CompareNICOrderOne" -eq "") {
  Write-Host "All good"
} else {
  Write-Host "Not good (expected $aNicOrderOne) - provided ($anicOrder)" 
}
```

Unfortunately above returns "" which means after comparison both Arrays are the same and in theory they are but order matters for me and in that case it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure there are only 3 elements you can just compare them directly in a loop. Set a flag that you can use if the elements don't match.

```
$orderFlag = $false

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {
  if ($aNICOrderOne[$i] -ne $aNICOrder[$i] ) {
    $orderFlag = $true
    break
  }
}

if($orderFlag) {
  write-host "Order not correct"
}
else {
  write-host "All good"
}
```

Comment: That's one of the approaches... true. Buf if number of elements change a bit it gets complicated.

Comment: Well not really - just use the `.length` property of the largest array and catch any `IndexOutOfRangeException`. This method might actually be faster as it will break on the first element that doesn't match and therefore may not have to read each array in its entirety

Answer (score 0):

This could also be solved using the `SyncWindow` parameter.

```
❯ [System.Collections.ArrayList] $aNICOrderOne = @("IBR","Service", "Admin")
❯ [System.Collections.ArrayList] $aNICOrder = @("Service","IBR", "Admin")
❯ Compare-Object $aNICOrder $aNICOrderOne -PassThru -SyncWindow 0

IBR
Service
Service
IBR
```